# LEDGER: How to sign all transaction with one approval?

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, ledger

Working on an idle NFT game and I want **Ledger** users to be able to send transactions only in one approval through their Ledger.

There are multiple transactions. When using a wallet extension `signAllTransactions` does the trick and allows signing all transactions only in one approval message. However, Ledger users need to approve all transactions 1 by 1 even though extensions ask only once.

Thinking about the logic of Ledger, It makes sense that it requires user to approve all transactions one by one but it is also a pain in the *ss when there are bunch of transactions and the intention is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ledgers are designed for safety, first and foremost, so they do not expose the ability to sign multiple transactions at once.

You'll need to do a workaround if you want this behavior, by having 1 transaction which requires the ledger to prefund some burner wallet and approve it to do certain things, and then you can use the burner wallet as much as needed!